# Electronic alternative to bicycle map

Tags: online-resources, bicycles, maps, gps-navigation

I plan a bicycle trip over Europe. Most likely I will follow one of the EuroVelo routes, but I might change my plans during the trip. So I would need to take too many paper maps.

Can you recommend any of the following:

- some reliable online map (Google Maps are not good enough), or
- Android app with GPS and reliable bicycle maps
- GPS device, that would serve well for cycling

Also that would need to cover most of Europe, or at least the European Union part of it.

Comment: My question is about using GPS navi or online maps for cycling (while other question is about car navigation)

Comment: So what is the difference for you? If it's about maps that contain bicycle maps, did you even try to check those in the answers of the duplicate question?

Comment: I take it there's no EuroVelo apps then? :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any websites or resources for planning bicycle routes across western Europe?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13680/are-there-any-websites-or-resources-for-planning-bicycle-routes-across-western-e)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Open Cycle Map](http://www.opencyclemap.org) provides a good coverage of Europe.

On the [GPS section](http://www.opencyclemap.org/gps/), you can find a device recommendation suited for cycling, as well as [how to put Open Street Maps on it](http://blog.gravitystorm.co.uk/2007/01/07/osm-on-my-gps/).